# Add Post Tags Taxonomy automatically from Post Genre Taxonomy

Tags: php, wordpress, taxonomy, custom-taxonomy, taxonomy-terms

I created a custom WordPress Post Taxonomy called “genre”

And Is it possible to add post genres Taxonomy values in post tags meta field automatically after saving/publishing post.

Means if i added “File Manager” and “Tools” genre in post then the same thing also goes added in post tags field automatically after Publishing/saving post.

And I also want to prepend “Android” and Append “Download” word in that tags that’ll added from that Genre Taxonomy.

I tried below code but not working properly if i add multiple Genre in post because all generes combines together and makes a single tag:

```
add_action('save_post','getags');
function getags($post_id) {
    $taxonomy = 'post_tag';
    $terms = 'Android'.get_the_term_list( $post_id, 'genre').'Download';
 return wp_set_object_terms($post_id, $terms, $taxonomy);
}
```

Comment: You should have a look at the `save_post` hook. https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/save_post/ . You can trigger any function you need on save. So you can create same tags for this post if you want

Comment: @Pof Yes, But i don't know to create function to do this, Please share any code snippets if you know?

Comment: You have an example on my link. You just have to add this function to you php and customize the function with what you want. I can help you debug your code, but I'll not do everything for you, sorry.

Comment: @Pof I tried this but not working properly if i add multiple Genre in post because all genres combines together and makes a single tag:

```
add_action('save_post','getags');
function getags($post_id) {
 $taxonomy = 'post_tag';
 $terms = 'Android'.get_the_term_list( $post_id, 'genre').'Download';
 return wp_set_object_terms($post_id, $terms, $taxonomy);
}
```
Do you have any solutions?

Comment: Please read the doc when you're using functions : https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_term_list/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use the `save_post` hook, and loop through your current terms with the `get_the_terms()` function.

```
add_action('save_post','getags');
function getags($post_id) { 
  $genres = get_the_terms( $post_id, 'genre');
  $taxonomy = 'post_tag'; 
  foreach($genres as $genre) {
    $terms = 'Android '.$genre->name.' Download'; 
    wp_set_object_terms( $post_id, $terms, $taxonomy, true );
  } 
}
```

`get_the_term_list()` is used to retrieve a list of terms. `get_the_terms()` gives you an array, easier to use.

Comment: It's not working

Comment: I did small changes to your code and now below code is working **But only one genre is adding in tags field not all that i added in my post, Do you know any solution for that?**: `add_action('save_post','getags'); 

function getags($post_id) { 
  $genres = get_the_terms( $post_id, 'genre');
  $taxonomy = 'post_tag'; 
  foreach($genres as $genre) {
    $terms = 'Android '.$genre->name.' Download'; 
    wp_set_object_terms($post_id, $terms, $taxonomy); 
  } 
}`

Comment: Hello, After modifying your code problem is solved so have edited your Answer with correct codes.